# Hostable chatroom that is accessible from multiple services

Tags: chat

I was curious if there was a service that provided a chatroom that is accessible from multiple chat services. We have been using IRC for a university organization's chatroom, but newer members are less likely to be willing to dig up an IRC client to use. Popular chat services come and go, so I was wondering if it was possible to keep a cross chat service room up.

If not, I'd have to program up a series of chatbots, or get everyone to agree for once.

Requirements:

- At least two chat service types in the same chat room able to communicate to each other. The more the better. Such as:

  - IRC
  - XMPP
  - AIM
  - GChat
- Persistant. Possible hosted by FreeNAS or a cloud service.

Wanted:

- IRC support at least.
- GChat or Facebook would be good. (And unlikely, I bet.)
- Maybe Mumble support?

I'm mostly curious if there's a good service like this. I won't be too surprised if there isn't.